# Encoding of AVMetadataItem

Tags: ios, encoding, utf-8, avmetadataitem

I have a AVMetadataItem which has fields encoded in CP1251 (Cyrillic). After reading item.stringValue I get garbage - incorrectly encoded string.
I've tried converting that string to raw UTF8 and then creating a new string using the CP1251 encoding - no luck, result is nil. Tried taking the item.dataValue - no dice, it contains a raw list data (starting with bplist...).

Any ideas are very appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Tried comparing at the actual bytes of the utf8 decoded item.stringValue with the bytes of the original CP1251-decoded metadata string? Since it didn't work for you they probably won't be the same, but maybe you can find some hint.

Comment: Does it work if you do the decoding yourself, getting the item's dataValue instead of stringValue and decoding it with [[NSString alloc] initWithData:encoding:]? If that doesn't do it, can you add the garbage string to this question so that we can sort out what encodings it's been mangled with?

Comment: No it didn't work for me. But I'll try to post the hex values of the data I get from dataValue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've ended up using Mike Ash's NSPropertyListReader_binary1 and getting the raw data and then mangling it so that NSString would it it's encoding.

Horrible - but worked.

Comment: Ah, interesting. Does it look like it was just an error in decoding the string, or was it mangling the data somehow?

Comment: There's the thing - inside the MP3 the ID3 tag was CP1251 encoded (I checked the binary file), but after reading it using the AVAsset - the data is interpreted as UTF16 - thus mangling the data. I used the custom plist reader to get the actual data and de-mangle it manually.

Comment: @reflog - Could you please post the solution you've found using NSPropertyListReader_binary1 or have a quick look at my question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16001847/correct-encoding-for-id3-tags-in-ios)? I've faced the same problem and spent a lot of time trying to solve it. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

Swift 2.0 solution:

```
let origTitleMeta: NSData = (<AVMetadataItem>.timedMetadata?.first?.stringValue?.dataUsingEncoding(NSISOLatin1StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true))!

let convertedTitleMeta: String = String(data: origMeta, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
```

Answer (score 2):

I have AVMetadataItem extension for this:

```
extension AVMetadataItem {

    /// stringValue: ISO-8859-1 → UTF-8
    var utf8String: String? {
        guard let data = stringValue?.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: true) else {
            return nil
        }
        return String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 3.0 solution:

```
let data: Data = item.timedMetadata!.first!.stringValue.data(using: String.Encoding.isoLatin1, allowLossyConversion: true)!

let title: String = String(data: data as Data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)!
```