# Correct encoding for ID3 Tags in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, audio, encoding, id3-tag

I'm trying to get ID3 tags from a bunch of mp3 files in my project.

```
AudioFileGetProperty(audioFile, kAudioFilePropertyInfoDictionary, &size, &metadataDictionary);
```

If the tag doesn't contain cyrillic symbols, the output looks OK on the device. However I sometimes get values like this one:

```
album = "\U00ce\U00f2\U00ea\U00f0\U00fb\U00f2\U00ee\U00e5 \U00d0\U00e0\U00e4\U00e8\U00ee 102.5FM";
"approximate duration in seconds" = "260.623";
```

and it leads to distorted symbols display (http://d.pr/i/X9wG).

Is there any way to decode these symbols into a readable form? I've already tried

```
NSString* value = [metadataDictionary objectForKey: key];
NSData* data = [value dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSString* string = [[NSString alloc] initWithData: data encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding];
```

but the result stays the same.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

**[UPDATE]**

I tend to try a solution provided in [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9794280/1136481), but are there any other ways?

Answer (score 1):

That's way to decode these symbols into a readable form:

```
NSString *value = [metadataDictionary objectForKey:@"artist"];
const char *cString = [value cStringUsingEncoding:NSWindowsCP1252StringEncoding];
NSString *artist = [NSString stringWithCString:cString encoding:NSWindowsCP1251StringEncoding];
```